# Count overlapps of overlapping features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, overlapping-features, turf

Can anyone suggest how to implement a feature similar to Count Overlapping Features (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/count-overlapping-features.htm), but on JavaScript? Picture of an example from the article.

I have some number of polygons (about 100). I would like to get all areas of polygon overlay and their number.

As tools used: OpenLayers, turf (or jsts).

[image: Example image:]

For example, this option only makes me understand that all my polygons have some kind of intersection / overlap:

```
allPoly.forEach(poly1 => {
        poly1.properties.overlap = 0;    
        allPoly.forEach(poly2 => {
            let isIntersects = turf.intersect(poly1, poly2);
            if (isIntersects) {
                poly1.properties.overlap++;
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply counting intersects you would need to create new features using the results of `intersect` and `difference` operations, successively working through the features and applying further `intersect` and `difference` operations to the results already obtained, keeping a count of the intersections involved in each part.  Best illustrated by drawing new features to a source, otherwise you would need separate sources for the origin features and the results.

```
const source = new VectorSource({wrapX: false});

const style = new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'blue',
    width: 2,
  }),
  text: new Text({
    font: 'bold 12px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'back',
    }),
  }),
});

const vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  style: (f) => {
    style.getText().setText(f.get('intersects').toString());
    return style;
  },
});

const draw = new Draw({
  source: source,
  type: 'Circle',
});
map.addInteraction(draw);

const format = new GeoJSON();

draw.on('drawend', (e) => {
  e.feature.setGeometry(fromCircle(e.feature.getGeometry()));
  let newFeature = format.writeFeatureObject(e.feature);
  const diffs = [];
  source.getFeatures().forEach((f) => {
    if (!f.getGeometry()) {
      return;
    }
    const intersects = f.get('intersects');
    const feature = format.writeFeatureObject(f);
    let intersect = turf.intersect(feature, newFeature);
    if (intersect) {
      intersect = format.readFeature(intersect);
      intersect.set('intersects', intersects + 1);
    }
    let diff1 = turf.difference(feature, newFeature);
    if (diff1) {
      diff1 = format.readFeature(diff1);
      diff1.set('intersects', intersects);
    }
    if (intersect) {
      source.removeFeature(f);
      source.addFeature(intersect);
      if (diff1) {
        source.addFeature(diff1);
      }
    }
    let diff2 = turf.difference(newFeature, feature);
    diffs.push(diff2);
  });
  diffs.forEach((d) => {
    newFeature = newFeature && d ? turf.intersect(newFeature, d) : null;
  });
  if (newFeature) {
    newFeature = format.readFeature(newFeature);
    e.feature.setGeometry(newFeature.getGeometry());
    e.feature.set('intersects', 1);
  } else {
    e.feature.setGeometry();
  }
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-features-forked-mfuetc?file=/main.js

Comment: I added some relevant code from CodeSandbox example.

Comment: @Mike, thank you! This looks very interesting. I'll try to adapt this option to my data.

Comment: @TomazicM, thanks for the CodeSandbox example.

Comment: @luzhskij CodeSandbox example is Mike's work, I just added part of the code to the answer.